# Using dataframe for sorting and plotting values

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I have a set of coordinates /clicks from a survey. I would like to create a heatmap of those clicks but with a background image.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from PIL import Image

#import the excel file 
file = 'pidxyemo.xlsx'
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
df1 = xl.parse('Sheet1')
df2 = df1[np.isfinite(df1['X'])]
numpyMatrix = df2.as_matrix() #<---I have my data points here 

#the image I would like to use as background
img = Image.open("C:\\Users\\Judita\\Desktop\\body.png")

#I saw that someone used the following to make a heat map 
"""
x = np.random.randn(88)
y = np.random.randn(88)

heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=50)
extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]


plt.imshow(heatmap.T, extent=extent, origin='lower')
plt.show()
"""
```

When I do this, I have two seperate images rather than an imgae on the background and the heat map superimposed on the image.

Is there a way to have background images while making a heat map? Im new here and to programming , please say if I need to explain more.

thanks!

Comment: If the heatmap is superimposed on the image, how would you then still expect to see the image?

Comment: You would need to make the heatmap transparent (maybe by defining colorrange to make transparent) and paste that image on top of your background image (search for paste image pil). Definately doable. (Just som thoughts)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. The image is an outline of human body and I need to show heat maps of clicks. @Anton , thanks , I will try to make the heat map as image and paste it on the background. :)

Comment: @user8349986 no problems. Come back here, for instance, when you have two equal-sized images and paste them but you can't get the transparency to work. I think there are people that can help if you can provide two image samples.